# .collect method get an error undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to have a drop down list but when i try it it give me

undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

the controller:

```
def existing

                @courses = Course.all

    end
    def duplicate
        course = Course.find_by_id(permitd_up[:id])
        new_course = course.dup
        if new_course.save
            redirect_to :action => 'show'
        else
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end
```

the view:

```
<h3>Choose a Course</h3>
    <%= form_for :course , url: {:action => "duplicate" , method: "post"} do |f|%>
        <%= f.select :id , @courses.collect{|c| [c.id , c.name]} %>
    <br><br>
    <%= f.submit%>

    <%end%>
```

Comment: Can you post your full controller code?

Comment: Make sure you have a `course` record in your `courses` table.

Answer (score 2):

You will receive the following error

```
undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass
```

on

```
<%= f.select :id , @courses.collect{|c| [c.id , c.name]} %>
```

Only when `@courses` instance variable **was not set in the action that rendered this particular view.**

I see that `@courses` variable is set in the `existing` method. If you are using `existing` as an action which renders this view then your view name must be `existing.html.erb`.

Or if you are rendering the view from a different action then in that case you should set `@courses` value in that particular action by either directly setting the value within action OR by calling `existing` method from there.

Comment: Where is `existing.html.erb` located, share the path? And what is the controller name which has `existing` action.

Comment: the controller name is course and the existing is in the course view .. /app/views/courses/existing

Comment: Your controller name should be `CoursesController` (file name courses_controller.rb) and the `existing.html.erb` should be in `app/views/courses` folder.

Comment: and they are exactly what you said

Comment: What is the rails version you using? Do you actually have any records in Courses table?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your courses as a database table, you might want to try using rails' built in field helper `collection_select`. It will populate your select field with all of the data available in your model. If you want a drop-down like the one you are describing, I believe using collection select is the best way to handle it.

You can read up on it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Alternatively, if you have a ton of courses, maybe try looking into using a text field with autocomplete. Jquery UI has a plugin that makes this very easy. You can check out the railscasts for it here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised.

It requires a pro account but if you do a lot of rails developing it will be the best $9 you spend every month.

If you would like to continue to do it this way, make sure that you are defining 
`@courses = Courses(:all)` in the correct controller action, otherwise you will have nothing to render.

Comment: i tried the collection_select and it gives me the same error